# Need an idea for A star search algorithm with multiple goals

Tags: algorithm, a-star

The algorithm of A star search with a specified goal is pretty straightforward. However, what if there are multiple goals in a graph. For instance; you may want to find a shortest path that must include previously specified nodes. Constraint here is say your path must include A, B and C nodes( or more) not just find a path to node A or B or C. And of course the graph includes one or more A, B, C type nodes. So there is a question how can I **adapt** the A star search algorithm for **multiple goals**?

edit : we can visit nodes more than one.

Comment: You are describing conditions on **path** and not conditions on **goal**. A*, like all search algorithms - is finding a path to a goal [could be in a set, of goal, no problems with that]. Your problem [for the general case] is equivalent to the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: @amit, sorry, forgot to say visiting issue, I edited. Thank you.

Comment: Just spotted the bit about "And of course the graph includes one or more A, B, C type nodes" does that mean that graph can have more than one of each i.e. A,B,C are sets of nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are describing conditions on path and not conditions on goal. A*, like all search algorithms - is finding a path to a goal [could be in a set, of goal, no problems with that].

Your problem [for the general case] is at least as hard as the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), and thus this problem is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard).

The reduction is simple: Given an instance of TSP - find the shortest path from a certain `v` to `v` such that the path is going through all vertices [constraint]. You can do it by simply marking each vertex with a different mark.

Note however, that `A*` algorithm has no problem to find shortest path to a vertex in a **set of goal vertices**. Remember that A* is based on [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), which is finding shortest path to **all vertices** from a single source.

Comment: it's NP hard, but that is based on the number of nodes in the path constraint. So you could have a huge graph, and you'll still be able to quickly calculate the optimal path if you have only a couple of As, Bs, and Cs... See Peter's answer.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: As I said, the *general problem* is NP-Hard. Also, I believe there is a `O(n^3 + k^2*2^k)` solution to this problem, base on dynamic programming solution of TSP, which is better then the trivial `O((n^2logn)^(k!))` solution of "check all permutations on A,B,C..."

Answer (score 2):

You have a set `z` of all nodes, goal node `G`, and sets `a` though `y` of sub-goal nodes. Starting from `S`, the starting node, path to all nodes in `a` through `y`. Then, from those path to nodes in `a` through `y`, but if a route has already gone through a `c` node for example ignore all `c` nodes for that branch. Cull branches that move away from the eventual goal until you read the final goal state and have a path that runs through all known sub-goal states.

Hope that makes sense. I'll get a diagram up shortly, which might help.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.. Compute shortest paths from S->A, S->B, S->C, select the shortest (say to B), compute shortest path from B->C and B->A, select the shortest (say C), compute shortest path C to A. Then add the paths together.

[Edit]
Ok its not quite that simple. I think you could use A* to evalute shortest paths for all permutations between Start, A, B, C (which includes S->every node in the goal sets, each node in A to each in B etc.) and pick the shortest combination.

Comment: It fails if `S->B` is shorter then `S->A`, `S->C`, but `w(u,v) = VERY_LARGE` for all `u in B`

Comment: Assume you find a shortest path `S->B`, which is of length [weight] `l`. But, there is a path of length `l+1` to some `u in A`, and a path of length 1 from `u` to some `v in B` and another path of length 1 from `v` to some `w` in C. There is a path `S->...->u->v->w` of length `l+3`. However, you found a path to some `x in B`, with length `l`. but, all edges from `l` are of weight 50. It makes the solution that started with `x` [and was chosen, because it is the best at first] to be at cost `l+50` at least. And it is not the shortest path

Comment: @meandbobbymcgee: This is expected - since the problem is NP-Hard, it is not likely that there is a polynomial solution to it.

Comment: Amit what does 'u in A', 'v in B' mean please?

Comment: @PeterWishart: `A` is a set of all vertices that fit the criteria `A`, `u` is some vertex in this set. If you look at this as `A` is a vertex in your solution, just replace `u in A` with `A` in my comment.

Comment: @PeterWishart: You should also have a look at the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) in order to understand better what is the problem with this approach.