# How to determine a Heuristic for an algorithm, say A*, is a good one

Tags: artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I am recently learning A* algorithm, I know it takes a heuristic value when finding the potential path, and I also understand what consistent and admissible is for a heuristic. But I am confused that what kind of heuristic is good and why is it good?

BTW, how does heuristics work?

Comment: I think it depends entirely on the problem. Do you have any specific problem to solve? Like TSP or Number Scramble?

Comment: For example, a pacman is in the grid map, there are more than 1 food pallet to eat. How to eat all the food pallets with the least nodes been expanded?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting a heuristic is, in my opinion, mostly dependent on the problem. Yet, selecting a heuristic becomes easier if the problem is understood in a goal-oriented fashion. At least thats what I do. The idea I follow is this:

***The heuristic evaluates to zero at the goal state.***

So what are all the scenarios ? What are all the functions that yield zero at the goal?

> > **Possible Heuristics**
>
> 1. Number of food pallets left?
> 2. Distance of the current pallet to the Next Unexplored Pallet?
> 3. Unexplored Area in the grid with food pallets etc

I would go with the last option since it seems more reliable, though all the three will eventually lead to the solution.

> So, I believe, you select a heuristic by putting yourself at the goal
> state and then look back and see what all you have accomplished on the
> way. So in a sense, a heuristic is nothing but an approximation of
> what needs to be accomplished ( which evaluates to 0 at the goal).

Comment: thank you for your reply. But I still very confused, what exactly is a good heuristic? Based on the pacman problem, could you tell me the probable heuristic for it you come up with?

Comment: I dont have a working code for pacman. But have a look here http://imbhargav.wordpress.com/2013/01/19/a-starsearch/. A working code for Shortest Path Problem in A*.

Comment: If a map has multiple goals, do we return the total heuristic of each goal as a heuristic or just one each time?

Comment: Have a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555813/need-an-idea-for-a-star-search-algorithm-with-multiple-goals

Comment: after reading through the whole thread, I still got no idea about it. thank you anyway