# A* search with multiple-goals (Python)

Tags: python, search

I am trying to write a function that completes an A* search with multiple goals. Basically it is searching a grid like structure of the form:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%.           ...P .%
%.%%.%%.%%.%%.%% %.%
% %% %.....      %.%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

for a path from P that goes through all the dots (basically Pacman).

However I have run into a problem with my algorithm (which I attempted to adapt from my A* search for a single goal) as the path it returns does not go through all the dots. This is the path it returns for the above maze:

Path = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12), (1, 13), (1, 14), (1, 15), (1, 16)]

while a print statement shows that the visited variable has a value at return of:

[(1, 16), (1, 15), (2, 16), (1, 17), (1, 14), (3, 16), (1, 18), (1, 13), (3, 15), (2, 18), (1, 12), (2, 13), (3, 18), (3, 14), (1, 11), (3, 13), (3, 12), (1, 10), (1, 9), (3, 11), (2, 10), (1, 8), (3, 10), (1, 7), (3, 9), (1, 6), (3, 8), (2, 7), (1, 5), (3, 7), (1, 4), (3, 6), (2, 4), (1, 3), (3, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1)]

I think that that problem is how I am storing the current path (where each node stores its parent node, and then I return the end node and go backwards recursively to get the path). Does anyone have any advice for what I should change? I attached my current code below. Thanks!

Comment: Edit: the check_goal function checks that every node in dot_locs (the location of dots on the grid) is in the visited list.

Answer (score 1):

What your algorithm is currently doing is trying to find the goal by expending its area around the starting point and finding the best path for every node its visiting.

In a single-goal situation, it works well and you can get the path to this goal.
However how you have adapted it to a multi-goal purpose is that only the stop condition changes (when all goals as been visited once), meaning that you found the shortest path from the start point to each goal but not a single path visiting all nodes.

In the case, you just want the paths from the start point to each goal, just get the path (via parents) from each goal point.

If you really want to implement a pacman-like search, this is NP-Hard problem (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9555966/3830915)).

As one of the comment proposes, if you have a small list of goals, you can find a solution with brute-force:
Let's say you have 3 goals: A,B,C (which were dots):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%A              P  %
% %% %% %% %%C%% % %
% %% %   B       % %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Using your algorithm, you can find the shortest path from P to A, then A to B then B to C. Do the same for other permutations (`(P,A,C,B)`,`(P,B,A,C)` ...): see [`itertools.combinations(goals, len(goals))`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

You can then use your algorithm to find the path from one point to the other:

```
def A_multiple_goals(maze, start, goals):
    paths = []
    for itinerary in itertools.combinations(goals, len(goals)):
        path = get_path(A_search_multiple(maze, start, itinerary[0])) # First go to first goal from start
        for i in range(1 , len(itinerary)): # Then from each goal, goto the next one
            path += get_path(A_search_multiple(maze, itinerary[i-1], itinerary[i]))
        paths.append(paths)
    return min(paths, key=len)
```

This is a brute-force approach, if you have a lot of goals, you would need a better algorithm based around the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Comment: I move both the node_n.parent = curr statements on the inside of the if/else statements, but that did not change anything. What did you mean by "(Replace also the node.parent). I added find_neighbors and Node to the code above if that helps you. Thanks!

Comment: `node_n.parent = curr` should be placed inside the the first if but only inside the second `if` of the first `else` statement, otherwise the parent will always be overrided. What you want is to only set it when you are going to use that path.

Comment: I did that, it did not make a difference (although there may be a bigger bug that is masking it)

Comment: Ok, I managed to reproduce your results. What your algorithm is doing right now is sending "multiple pacmans" throught each path and marking the nodes as visited. However you are returning only the Pacman that visited the last node remaining for your rewards to be all found. What do you want to achieve ? If you want all the path to claim the result, just get all the path from each reward cell and find if one of the path is included on the other; if you only want "one" pacman", store a visited_nodes for each current_one (in the Node object)

Comment: Basically what I need is to return the optimal path the starting node through all the dots on the grid. What's the easiest way to stop it from sending multiple pacmans? I thought A* was supposed to return the optimal path (or at least a valid path)

Comment: Edited answer regarding your comment.